# Tweak how computer reads CSS language

Tags: css

Question is how to change how Ubuntu (or other distro) reads CSS (e.g. in Firefox/Chrome) to make it still work but to disable certain features like box-shadow, borders, turn off hovering.
Stylish allows to hide them after they are loaded but I would want to disable them completely.
I know it is not so important but still a nice way to personalize or optimize, if it isn't something that is very hard..

Answer (score 3):

The operating system does not decide how to render css, this is done by the browsers.

The only option you have is to use a user css extension, and define a rule like this:

```
* { box-shadow: none !important; border: none !important; }
```

This will make them not render.

Comment: You can also throw in `text-shadow: none !important;`